# How to get the exact number of positions after a decimal for the round() function

Tags: python, algorithm

Lets say that I have

`float_number = 3.05321355"`

I want to limit my result to just 5 characters (after I convert it to a string). So the result would be 5 characters counted from the left (including the decimal point), and that would be the position after the decimal that I want to add to the round() function.

5 character version of float_number:

`float_number_5_char = 3.053`

it is **3** decimal positions after the decimal point so that is where I want to round up to.

`round(float_number, 3)`

Is there an algorithm or way I can find out the number of decimal positions of any floating point for 5 characters max?

Another example:

```
float_1 = 32.53235
float_1_5_char = 32.53
```

So this is **2** decimal positions after the decimal point.

```
float_2 = 0.53235
float_2_5_char = 0.532
```

So this is **3** decimal positions after the point.

I tried to come up with something like this:

```
round_place = len(str(value)) - len(str(value)[:5])
```

But that doesn't work for all floating numbers.

Edit: The function's preconditions are that the value is from 0-999.99

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that wouldn't do rounding.

Comment: what would `123456789.0` rounded to 5 places be?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that point. The function's preconditions are that the value is from 0-999.99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positive numbers, you can get the number of digits to the left of the decimal with a simple formula:

```
left = int(math.log10(x))+1 if x >= 10 else 1
```

Now you can round:

```
r = round(x, n - 1 - left)
```

Comment: Darn... beat me to it by ten seconds. This is the correct solution. Have an upvote. :)

Comment: Would n be the number of characters that I limited to? (for example 5)

Comment: @nhbjgfcxhgchg too bad you didn't notice my off-by-one error. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @Naz yes, that's what `n` represents.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers never have an exact number of digits. If you need output precision just use string formating for proper character count:

```
five_chars = lambda num: ("%.3f" if num<1 else "%.5g") % num
float1 = five_chars(32.53235)
float2 = five_chars(0.53235)
```

gives:

```
32.53
0.532
```